# Downloading fails at random for our users from S3, need help figuring out what's wrong

Tags: nginx, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a file sharing service where users can upload, share and download their files. We are using AWS S3 to store our files.

We're facing an issue where small files download fine, but when files are bigger than 1 GB, the downloading drops/fails after some time, and it's completely random. Mostly it happens when there is a high downloading activity by our users during office working hours. The error users see when downloading drops is **"Failed - Network error"**.

When user downloads any file we do some preprocessing on that download, for example, we record the downloaded file, save analytics data, record the bandwidth, etc. Later we download the file straight from S3 URL.

Code to download the file is:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FILENAME.EXT"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('X-Accel-Redirect: ' . rawurlencode(  S3_FILEPATH  ) );
```

Here `S3_FILEPATH` is a url like `/s3/ PATH_TO_FILE ? QUERY_STRING`

That URL passes to nginx proxy settings are:

```
location ~* ^/s3/(.*) {
  proxy_http_version      1.1;

  proxy_set_header        Authorization '';
  proxy_set_header        Connection "";

  proxy_pass_header       X-Access;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-id-2;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-request-id;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-server-side-encryption;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-meta-lastmodifieddate;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-meta-size;
  proxy_hide_header       x-amz-meta-type;
  proxy_hide_header       Set-Cookie;
  proxy_ignore_headers    "Set-Cookie";

  resolver                10.0.0.2 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout        10s;

  proxy_buffering         off;
  proxy_intercept_errors  on;

  proxy_pass              http://s3.amazonaws.com/$1;
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out why this drop in downloading happens. What am I doing wrong? What should I do to make the downloading reliable? I found help related to configuration, but found nothing on how to make downloading reliable.

I will be very grateful if the community can help me figure out why this is happening and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Please try to reproduce this, then edit your question to include the access log entry and any applicable error log entry. It would also be interesting to see if the web browser developer tools in Chrome / Firefox says anything interesting.

Comment: @Tim there is no specific error in the log related to this. Nothing in nginx log or PHP log. Browser only shows "Failed - Network error".

Comment: So you have one network connection that is used for hosting your web server and serving files? Are these files public or unique to a user? You should consider using a CDN, which can help even if the files are unique to each user, and can help a lot more if they're common. Be careful to set your caching headers if you use a CDN.